# How to have have a separator/divider between bootstrap nav-tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some tabs defined via Bootstrap like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#panel-myRules" data-toggle="tab">My Rules</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#panel-activeRules" data-toggle="tab">Active Rules</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#panel-inactiveRules" data-toggle="tab">Inactive Rules</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to put some space between the 2nd and the 3rd tab or have a separator between them. Bootstraps's `divider` class does not work for tabs defined as `nav-tabs`.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you use an ID on that tab? Or, are the tabs always in the same position? A simple CSS rule should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a CSS rule:

```
.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) {margin-right: 10px;}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/oLLb5aj2/)

Or:

```
#myTabId {...}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/oLLb5aj2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

i think you want it if i understand well:

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lwe9yaq/3/

CSS:

```
    .nav.nav-tabs > li.active a {
        border: 0;
    }
    .nav.nav-tabs li:not(:last-child) a {
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 0;    
    }
.nav.nav-tabs li a {
  border-radius: 0; /* avoid curved divisor corner */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div role="tabpanel">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#panel-myRules" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My Rules</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#panel-activeRules" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Active Rules</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#panel-inactiveRules" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Inactive Rules</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="panel-myRules">Tab 1</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="panel-activeRules">Tab 2</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="panel-inactiveRules">Tab 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**note:** i used bootstrap  v3.3.1